# Is there a way to graph 2 different things in splitscreen mode in TI-Basic?

Tags: texas-instruments, ti-basic

I am trying to make a program for my calculator (TI-89 Titanium if that helps) that takes a function from user input and graphs it on the left side of the screen. Then it will apply a transformation to the function and graph it on the right side of the screen. The reason I think this is possible is because you can split the screen with `setMode("Split Screen","LEFT-RIGHT")` and then `setMode("Split 1 App,"Graph")` and `setMode("Split 2 App,"Graph")`. I also used `setMode("Number of Graphs,"2")` before that because I was getting an error if I didn't. I can then graph stuff with `DrawFunc ""`, but it only goes onto one of the graphs. I can't figure out how to switch which graph I am drawing onto. I tried searching this and reading the documentation, but I couldn't find anything about it.

My Code:

```
program()
Prgm
StoGDB gdb1
setMode("Split Screen","LEFT-RIGHT")
setMode("Number of Graphs,"2")
setMode("Split 1 App,"Graph")
setMode("Split 2 App,"Graph")
ClrDraw
ZoomStd
ZoomSqr
DrawFunc 5*x^2-2
Pause
RclGDB gdb1
setMode("Split Screen","FULL")
EndPrgm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! I figured out how to do it after a long time... I just had to use the `switch()` function in order to switch which window I was calling the functions on.